# Using WMI to get Account Secuirty polices

Tags: windows, wmi, audit

1. As a network auditor I am using WMI to query windows PC and get relevent information.
2. secpol.msc gives the account and local policies. Is there a way that I can read all the parameters in the policy to check that users have configured them as per company norms.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`RSoP WMI Classes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the Group Policy settings and the  [`Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250) which basically is a set of excel files which contains the windows registry keys where is stored such info.